# How to add column header in unload command of Redshift in Python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-redshift

I want return as column header and upd_tracking_nbr as value but it's not working.

```
  sql="""UNLOAD (\'select ups_tracking_nbr from (
            SELECT {} as return, 1 AS rn
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ups_tracking_nbr,  2 AS rn
            FROM Schema.Table
            WHERE TRUNC(last_order_updated_dttm) > TRUNC(SYSDATE - 30))
            ORDER BY rn\')
            TO 's3://abc/ups/EXTRACT_FOR_file' \
            credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::xyz' \
            ALLOWOVERWRITE \
            DELIMITER  ',' \
            PARALLEL OFF;Commit;""".format(column_header)
```

Its throwing error as "column "return" does not exist". I want return to be passed as string so that can be used as column_header of the unload script.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNLOAD` has a [`HEADER`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html#HEADER) option, which solves your problem, and you can even leave out the `PARALLEL OFF` part. It simplifies your code a lot:

```
sql="""UNLOAD (\'SELECT ups_tracking_nbr
        FROM Schema.Table
        WHERE TRUNC(last_order_updated_dttm) > TRUNC(SYSDATE - 30))
        ORDER BY rn\')
        TO 's3://abc/ups/EXTRACT_FOR_file' \
        credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::xyz' \
        ALLOWOVERWRITE \
        DELIMITER  ',' \
        HEADER;Commit;"""
```

But for you to understand the problem you were having:

When you `UNION` two tables they need to have the same schema. What you're trying to do is:

```
SELECT 'foo' as return, 1 as rn
UNION ALL 
SELECT ups_tracking_nbr, 2 AS rn
...
```

the above will not work because one table has (`return`, `rn`) schema and the other one (`ups_tracking_nbr`, `rn`).